# How to deal with null value in table column in java?

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I am getting null pointer exception again and again while getting value from database table.....why its giving me null pointer exception?

Here is my code :

```
private HashSet getPlayerList() {
        HashSet hs = new HashSet();
        String soccername = "";
        try {
            conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            rs = null;
            pstmt = null;
            String sql = "Select * from Players where deleted = false";

            if (conn != null) {
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    soccername = rs.getString("soccername").trim();// this line giving exception
                    if (soccername == null || soccername.isEmpty()) {
                        soccername = rs.getString("name").trim();
                    }
                    hs.add(soccername);
                }
            }
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
                rs.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        return hs;
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is wrong:

```
soccername = rs.getString("soccername").trim();// this line giving exception
if (soccername == null || soccername.isEmpty()) {
```

if `rs.getString("soccername")` returns null it must leads to a NPE because it is followed by the function `trim()`.

better is:

```
soccername = rs.getString("soccername");
if (soccername == null || soccername.trim().isEmpty()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
soccername = rs.getString("soccername");
if (soccername == null || soccername.isEmpty()) {
    soccername = rs.getString("name").trim();
} else {
    //now you are sure that soccername is not null
    soccername = soccername.trim();
}
```